# Renaming belongsToMany association with Sequalize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Given this assocation

```
Product.Locations = Product.belongsToMany(ProductLocation, { 
   as: 'locations', 
   through: ProductStock,
   foreignKey: 'productId',
   otherKey: 'locationId'
});
```

The following model is loaded

```
const product = await Product.findById(123, { include: Product.Locations });
console.log(product);
// -> {
//   id: 123,
//   ....,
//   locations: [ {
//      ProductStock: { productId: 123, locationId: 456, stock: 99 },
//      id: 456,
//      ...
//   } ],
//   ...
// }
```

How do I change the name `ProductStock` to `stock` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code :

```
    var str=
    {
      id: 123,
      locations: 
      [ 
        {
            ProductStock: { productId: 123, locationId: 456, stock: 99 },
            id: 456,
        },
      ],
    };
    var str2=
    {
      id:str.id,
      locations:
      [
        {
          stock:
          { 
            productId:str.locations[0].ProductStock.productId,
            locationId:str.locations[0].ProductStock.locationId,
            stock:str.locations[0].ProductStock.stock
          },
          id:str.locations[0].id
        }
      ]
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(str2));
```

Comment: This does not help, I am aware of mapping objects, but the problem is with Sequalize; it behaves badly when there are aliases while saving, and the support from `through` table is far less documented.

Comment: @YanickRochon through: stock, just make this change in your associations.